# Which is the better constructor? Empty or using fields?

Tags: java, class

I am currently taking an Android class and when I got the first assignment grade, I lost points due to using an empty constructor rather than using one with fields.  The professor said using fields is better.  Is he correct?  If so, why?

Is this better?

```
Photos pic = new Photos(path, title, author, date);

public Photos(String url_path, String title, String author,
        String date_taken) {
    super();

    this.url_path = url_path;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.date_taken = date_taken;
}
```

Or this?  Or does it matter?

```
 Photos pic = new Photos();
 pic.setUrl_path(path);
 pic.setTitle(title);
 pic.setAuthor(author);
 pic.setDate_taken(date);

 public Photos() {
    super();

 }
```

Comment: It depends if Photos is designed to be immutable or mutable, just from top of my head... And definitely many reasons for doing it one way or another.

Comment: Put *mandatory* values into constructor, leave *optional* values outside

Comment: Also, note that `photos` should be `Photos`... constructors have to have the same name as the class...

Comment: `"The professor said using fields is better."` - Did he add any more context to that statement?  By itself that recommendation is meaningless.  Neither approach is *inherently* better, they serve entirely different purposes.

Comment: The only other thing he said was it is less lines of code which I suppose makes sense but I still don't see how that makes it "better".

Comment: @WeVie: You'll find that professors aren't the only people who insist that their personal opinions are "better" than others.  Dogmatism is rampant in software development.  For example, "less lines of code" is also very subjective.  *Shorter* code isn't always *cleaner* code.

Comment: If LOCs is his only argument, then from the viewpoint of a person who is paid by LOCs he is utterly wrong ;)

Comment: @David carries a good point. I would say just go along with it for now, but in the future, remember that it's getting good, clean, and efficient code that matters, not the lines of it.

Comment: To follow up a little bit... Doing what the professor says is a good strategy to succeed *in that professor's class*.  Outside of that class, his opinions are no more valid than anybody else's and he has the same burden of demonstrable proof that anybody else has :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should prefer a constructor that is given initial values, to setting those values later using setter methods. But why?

It is possible to just think of an object as a bag for holding a jumbled collection of fields, which in theory could have any value,  including invalid values. In that case, using a no-args constructor followed by a setter would be OK.

But it transpired (in the 1970s) that programming in that way caused difficulties when creating large or complicated programs.

Imagine you had a `Person` class that had an attribute that recorded the name of the person, as a `String`, and the nature of your program was that you will, and **must**, always know the name of a person. As you must always have the name, it must never be `null`. If you have a no-args constructor, what value would it initialise the name to? It is not permitted to leave the name as null. But it makes no sense to set the name to an arbitrary default name, because there is no generally useful default for the name of a person.  So, if you want to impose the constraint that a `Person` object always has a (non `null`) name, your constructor must have an argument that tells it what the name of the new `Person` object will be.

It is useful to think of an object, not as a jumble of values, but as values that have constraints on them. It is very helpful if the code for that object is written in a way that makes it **impossible** to breach those constraints. Then, *any* code that uses that object can safely assume those constraints will be met, even if you do not know (or remember) what the other parts of the code do. This enables you to concentrate on one bit of the code at once, without having to examine elsewhere to check whether an important constraint will be met. In most cases, only constructors given initial values can construct an object that meets all the constraints.

Answer (score 4):

Neither is "better", they simply do different things.  Which one is subjectively "better" depends on what you want to achieve with that class.  Consider this code for example:

```
Photos pic = new Photos();
pic.setUrl_path(path);
pic.setTitle(title);
pic.setAuthor(author);
pic.setDate_taken(date);
```

Immediately following that first line, is the `pic` object in a valid state?  Does having no values set result in a meaningfully and contextually complete `Photos` object?  If the answer is "no" and if the fields being set are *necessary* in order to have a valid `Photos` object, then they should be required by the constructor.

That is, the job of the constructor is to ensure that only a valid instance is created.  Never assume that consuming code will follow up with setters, it might not.  The job of ensuring valid state of the object is a responsibility that should be encapsulated within the object.

On the other hand, if a parameterless constructor *can* create a valid instance of `Photos` then it's perfectly acceptable to have a parameterless constructor.  You can have both, so consuming code has the option of which to use depending on the state is wishes to create:

```
public Photos() {
    // set default values
}

public Photos(String url_path, String title, String author, String date_taken) {
    // set supplied values
}
```

It all depends on what a valid state of a `Photos` object can be and what is required (or not required) in order to achieve that state.

Answer (score 2):

When you use setter the objects are mutable and their state can be manipulated but anyone who has access to it.

The other approach makes the objects in a single defined state and are typically read-only once they are created as they cannot be modified from outside the class. How ever they can always be mutated inside the class.

Example:

```
public class Setters {
   private int value;
   public void setValue(int val) {
     value=val;
   }
   public int getValue() {
     return value;
   }
}

public void function(Setter setter){
    setter.setValue(20);
}


// In main 

Setter setter = new Setter();
setter.setValue(10);
function(setter);
System.out.println(setter.getValue());
```

In this case it will print 20 cause it is mutable

```
public class Setters {
   private int value;
   public setter(int val) {
     value=val;
   }
   public int getValue() {
     return value;
   }
}

// In main 

Setter setter = new Setter(10);
Setter setter1 = new Setter(20);
System.out.println(setter.getValue());
System.out.println(setter1.getValue());
```

This will print 10 and 20 you don't have a setter so these object will become read only after creation.

Comment: Stateless objects are objects without instance fields. An immutable field (set in constructor) gives an object with one state, not a stateless one.

Comment: @Tom what would you suggest for me to change.

Comment: @wrongAnswer how about `as they cannot be modified (but don't forget that their fields are still mutable (if it is a mutable type)).`?

Comment: @wrongAnswer I guess you misunderstood me :). Your change is correct, but I meant that if you grant access to fields that contains mutable types, like `Collection`, then the calling object could easily manipulate these fields (without assigning new objects to them, because there is no setter method)(e.g., `collection.clear()` or `collection.add(..)`). Read only sounds more like the object itselft and it's fields are immutable.

Comment: aah i see but in the getter we could return an immutable collection ;) :p

Comment: @wrongAnswer Could, yes, but the fact that there are no setter, does not imply this :D.

Comment: Yup ! that is correct i think it will be to complicated for the OP to understand that considering OP is beginner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62711/discussion-between-wronganswer-and-tom).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [Dmitry Bychenko in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238381/which-is-the-better-constructor-empty-or-using-fields#comment41155736_26238381), parameters are passed via the constructor, When the `construction` of an `object` **depends** upon those mandatory parameters.

The other parameters are generally set once the object has been constructed.

Take the example of the constructor of the `File` class,

```
File f = new File("filepath");
```

Here `filepath` is a parameter without which a `File` object cannot be constructed, since it needs to refer to a location where the file resides. And its attributes such as `readable`, can be set through the setters, and come into picture only after the file reference has been constructed successfully.

```
f.setReadable(arg0)
```

Since in your example, the `Photo` class doesn't depend upon any of its parameter values for its construction, a `parameterized` constructor is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what class you are writing. If it is for Immutable objects it means you are not to provide accessors / mutators for it. In that case its necessary that you provide initial values for attributes at time of creation of object. Natural choice would be to pass them in constructor.

In your case of Photos, the attributes like Title, Date_Taken and Author are not supposed to be changed or can't be null and are supposed to be associated with "Photos" right from the creation, so it is better practice to provide arguments in constructor. Although you can provide getter/setter for URL since its value can change with time.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of efficiency, yeah, it is.

You could do it like this...

```
JButton b = new JButton();
b.setText("Hello everybody 1");
b.setIcon(b1);

JButton c = new JButton();
c.setText("Hello everybody 2");
c.setIcon(c2);

JButton d = new JButton();
d.setText("Hello everybody 3");
d.setIcon(d3);

JButton e = new JButton();
e.setText("Hello everybody 4");
e.setIcon(e4);
```

Or you could do

```
JButton b = new JButton("Hello everybody 1", b1);

JButton c = new JButton("Hello everybody 2", c2);

JButton d = new JButton("Hello everybody 3", d3);

JButton e = new JButton("Hello everybody 4", e4);
```

Far more streamlined, yes? Not to mention that things like variables, of which most classes have several, can be given default values from the getgo, instead of having to give them passive values when you are not even going to use those variables anywhere in your program.

Answer (score 1):

If your object Photo (in this case) always has those attributes to be a valid photo
I believe you should include the assignment of those attributes in your constructor. (path, title, author, date);

And since your are making one photo object. The name of the constructor and class should be Photo (not Photos)

```
public Photo(String urlPath, String title, String author,
    String dateTaken) {
super();

this.urlPath= urlPath;
this.title = title;
this.author = author;
this.dateTaken= dateTaken;
```

}

Some more comments:

You only need to call super() if the Photo class is a derived class.
Use camel casing for your argument names and try to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Another aspect of consideration is how you want to wire together classes. If you are using dependency injection container like spring or guice, a empty constructor with setters and getters allows you to wire references from and to your object.

I prefer to separate object construction from execution, so as long as your code is factored in that way it would be modular, extensible and clean.